# VBA - Regex expression

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to set a rule for a alphanumeric string of 12 characters.

- It must have always letters (a-z or A-Z) and numbers (0-9). The length of each can vary, nonetheless it must have at least one of each elements.
- It must have exactly 12 chr in total.

My best try resulted in something like this:
EX: AB1111111111

^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]$

The problem is when I'm trying to define the max number of chr to 12 I cannot sate {12} , it doesn't work.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: You may actually just add `(?=.{12}$)` after `^` and append `*` to the last character class: `^(?=.{12}$)([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead for that :

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]{12}$/i
```

The last part tells "I want 12 chars of A-Z or 0-9"

The first part tells "I want at least 1 0-9"

The second part tells "I want at least 1 A-Z"

All that case insensitive with the `i` flag (but you can add A-Z if needed)

Fiddle here : https://regex101.com/r/lxKAvS/2

Comment: Thank you very much, for the explanation and the result. It works very good!